# Is this a possible way to encrypt a binary file with openpgp.js and how to save the file so it can be also handle 'manual' - in Filebrowser?

Tags: node.js, openpgp.js

I'm trying to read a binary file, to encrypt/decrypt and save/write it. 
Comparing the original file with the resulting file of the decryption leads to the same filehash. So I think it's a correct/possible way.

If I try to decrypt the file manually in Windows with GnuPG the it is stated that the file is verified but no usable file is saved. So my question is: How do I have to store the file that it could be used 'manually' also.

### Used sources

My code is based on following post:
https://commscentral.net/tech/?post=64

-> 
[example code of post on GitHub](https://github.com/adcreare/nodejs-demos/blob/master/openpgp.js/file-encryption-decryption-example-es-2017.js)

But I read that for dealing with a binary file/payload:

```
openpgp.message.fromBinary()
```

should be used.
->
https://github.com/openpgpjs/openpgpjs/issues/204#issuecomment-43065260

### My code

#### imports

```
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');
const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile);
const writeFile = util.promisify(fs.writeFile);
const openpgp = require('openpgp') // use as CommonJS, AMD, ES6 module or via window.openpgp
```

#### encryption

```
const encryptFuntion = async() => {
    openpgp.initWorker({ path:'openpgp.worker.js' }) // set the relative web worker path
    const pubkey = await readFile('pub.asc','utf8');
    const passphrase = `password`;
    const privkey = await readFile('priv.asc','utf8');
    const privKeyObj = (await openpgp.key.readArmored(privkey)).keys[0];
    await privKeyObj.decrypt(passphrase);
    const file = await readFile('test.txt');
    const fileArray = new Uint8Array(file);

    const options = {
        message: openpgp.message.fromBinary(fileArray),
        publicKeys: (await openpgp.key.readArmored(pubkey)).keys,
        privateKeys: [privKeyObj],
        armor:false
    };
    const encryptionResponse = await openpgp.encrypt(options);
    const encryptedFile = encryptionResponse.message.packets.write();
    await writeFile('test.txt.gpg',encryptedFile);
};
```

#### decryption

```
const decryptFuntion = async () => {
    openpgp.initWorker({path: 'openpgp.worker.js'}) // set the relative web worker path
    const passphrase = `password`;
    const privkey = await readFile('priv.asc', 'utf8');
    const pubkey = await readFile('pub.asc', 'utf8');
    const privKeyObj = (await openpgp.key.readArmored(privkey)).keys[0];
    await privKeyObj.decrypt(passphrase);
    const file = await readFile('test.txt.gpg');
    const fileArray = new Uint8Array(file);
    options = {
        message: await openpgp.message.read(file), // parse encrypted bytes
        privateKeys: [privKeyObj],              // decrypt with password
        publicKeys: (await openpgp.key.readArmored(pubkey)).keys,
        format: 'binary'                          // output as Uint8Array
    };
    const decryptionResponse = await openpgp.decrypt(options);
    const decryptedFile = decryptionResponse.data;
    await writeFile('test-decrypted.txt', decryptedFile);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps, did some changes to code based on my knowledge of NodeJS.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const openpgp = require('openpgp');
const async = require('async');

const encryptFuntion = () => {
    async.waterfall([
        (a_cb) => {
            fs.readFile('pub.asc', 'utf8', (err, pubkey) => {
                if (!err) {
                    a_cb(null, pubkey);
                } else {
                    a_cb(err);
                }
            });
        },
        (pubkey, a_cb) => {
            fs.readFile('priv.asc', 'utf8', (err, privkey) => {
                if (!err) {
                    const passphrase = `yourPassphrase`;
                    let privKeyObj = (await openpgp.key.readArmored(privkey)).keys[0];
                    await privKeyObj.decrypt(passphrase);
                    a_cb(null, pubkey, privKeyObj);
                } else {
                    a_cb(err);
                }
            });
        },
        (pubkey, privKeyObj, a_cb) => {
            fs.readFile('test.txt', 'utf8', (err, rawMessage) => {
                if (!err) {
                    a_cb(null, pubkey, privKeyObj, rawMessage);
                } else {
                    a_cb(err);
                }
            });
        },
        (pubkey, privKeyObj, message, a_cb) => {
            let options = {
                message: openpgp.message.fromText(message),
                publicKeys: (await openpgp.key.readArmored(pubkey)).keys,
                privateKeys: [privKeyObj],
                armor: false
            };
            openpgp.encrypt(options)
                .then((ciphertext) => {
                    a_cb(null, ciphertext);
                });
        }
    ], (err, ciphertext) => {
        if (!err) {
            fs.writeFile('test.txt.gpg', ciphertext.data, (err) => {
                if (!err) {
                    console.log('Created GPG file!');
                } else {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
        } else {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
};

const decryptFuntion = () => {
    async.waterfall([
        (a_cb) => {
            fs.readFile('test.txt.gpg', (err, encrypted) => {
                if (!err) {
                    a_cb(null, encrypted);
                } else {
                    a_cb(err);
                }
            });
        },
        (encrypted, a_cb) => {
            fs.readFile('pub.asc', 'utf8', (err, pubkey) => {
                if (!err) {
                    a_cb(null, encrypted, pubkey);
                } else {
                    a_cb(err);
                }
            });
        },
        (encrypted, pubkey, a_cb) => {
            fs.readFile('priv.asc', 'utf8', (err, privkey) => {
                if (!err) {
                    const passphrase = `yourPassphrase`;
                    let privKeyObj = (await openpgp.key.readArmored(privkey)).keys[0];
                    await privKeyObj.decrypt(passphrase);
                    a_cb(null, encrypted, pubkey, privKeyObj);
                } else {
                    a_cb(err);
                }
            });
        },
        (encrypted, pubkey, privKeyObj, a_cb) => {
            let options = {
                message: await openpgp.message.readArmored(encrypted),
                publicKeys: (await openpgp.key.readArmored(pubkey)).keys,
                privateKeys: [privKeyObj]
            };
            openpgp.decrypt(options)
                .then((plaintext) => {
                    a_cb(null, plaintext);
                });
        }
    ], (err, plaintext) => {
        if (!err) {
            fs.writeFile('test-decrypted.txt', plaintext, 'utf8', (err) => {
                if (!err) {
                    console.log('Created txt file!');
                } else {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
        } else {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
};

module.exports = {
    encryptFuntion, decryptFuntion
};
```

I could have gone wrong at file-content type, will using fs.readFile

Links referred to:
1. [Async waterfall](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#waterfall)
2. [Openpgp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/openpgp)
3. [Node FS Module](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)

PS: Its my way of learning something new every week, by re-writing code at stackoverflow.